# How to detect particular advanced instructions on ARM?

Tags: assembly, arm

In an ARM user-mode program, how could I detect whether, say, I'm on a machine that supports the AES cryptography instructions?  ARM seems to have made this difficult, unlike x86's very convenient `cpuid` instruction.

Comment: There's an undefined instruction trap. My guess is that you try to execute the instructions you want.  No trap == good to go.

Comment: Which OS are you using? It might have some CPU identification built in. Or at least a way of executing a command while catching the "Invalid instruction" exception.

Comment: there are many coprocessor registers that describe in detail what is available. but the question is can you get to them from user mode.

Comment: You could take a look at what OpenSSL is doing (which is the same idea proposed by Gene and Seva): [armv4cpuid.S](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/external/openssl/+/master/crypto/armv4cpuid.S), [armcap.c](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/external/openssl/+/master/crypto/armcap.c)

Comment: The undefined instruction trap is not good - sometimes instructions are unpredictable instead of undefined. Also, the coprocessor 15 is full of configuration registers and identification registers. Check them out first. Some of them are visible in user mode, some of them are not, and some are unpredictable if accessed from user mode. The architecture references tell...